# Unable to set validation rule for alphabetical characters in codeigniter

Tags: validation, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3, and I referred the various stackoverflow links having similar problem like mines. But I was not able to solve this issue. The callback function customAlpha is called from the file->MY_Form_validation.php, which is currently located in the libraries folder of my project. I changed the regular expression several times,but no use. Please help.

Controller->Login_c.php

```
<?php
class Login_c extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    { 
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->model('User/login_m');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    } 

    public function register_user()  
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'uname', 'Full Name',
        'trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[4]|callback_customAlpha',
        array(
                'required'      => 'Please provide %s.',
               'customAlpha'     => 'Only characters are allowed in Full Name field'
        )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('upass', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpass', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[upass]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('uemail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[user.uemail]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('umobile', 'Mobile Number', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]');

        if($this->input->post('oemail'))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('oemail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[user.oemail]');
            $oemail = $this->input->post('oemail');
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $errors['err'] = validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('User/signup.html',$errors);
        } 
        else 
        {
           //Code to store user entered data in database
        }
    }
}

?>
```

MY_Form_validation.php

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation 
    {

        public function __construct($rules = array())
        {
            parent::__construct($rules);
        }

        public function customAlpha($str)
        {
            //Validation for alphabetical characters and spaces
            if ( !preg_match('/^(?:[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+|$)){1}$/', $str) )
            {   
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        } 

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this issue on my own. Below is the solution that worked.

MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation 
{

    function __construct($config = array())
    {
      parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function customAlpha($str)
    {

        if ( !preg_match('/^([a-z]+(-| )?)+$/', $str) )
        {   
            return false;

        }
        else
        {
            return true;

        } 

    } 

}
```

Login_c.php

```
    class Login_c extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    { 
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->model('User/login_m');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    } 

    public function register_user()  
    {


        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'uname', 'Full Name',
        'required|min_length[4]',
        array(
                'required'      => 'Please provide %s.'
        )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('upass', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpass', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[upass]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('uemail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[user.uemail]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('umobile', 'Mobile Number', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]');

        $validation = $this->form_validation->customAlpha($this->input->post('uname'));

        if($this->input->post('oemail'))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('oemail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[user.oemail]');
            $oemail = $this->input->post('oemail');
        }
        else if ($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE) 
        {
            $errors['err'] = validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('User/signup.html',$errors);

        } 
        else if($validation == false)
        {   
            $errors['err'] = "Error in name field";
            $this->load->view('User/signup.html',$errors);
        }
        else 
        {
             //Code to store user entered data in database
        }
    }
}

?>
```